# Create datastore index on the fly in google app engine (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to create an index in the production datastore on the fly?  I would like to do some queries on data that can have properties added dynamically.

Comment: Compound index (multiple properties) or simple index (per property)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create indexes "on-the-fly" from your code.
What you can do is you can add the new indexes to your index configuration (datastore-indexes.xml in Java), and redeploy your application.

If you can't or don't want to redeploy your application for the new indexes, you can update the index configuration only using the app engine SDK:

```
./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh update_indexes myapp/war
```

or

```
appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.cmd update_indexes myapp/war
```

Note: you can also deploy a different version of your application with the new indexes, because indexes are shared among different versions.